# date function into a class doesn't work

Tags: php, class, datetime

I wrote a class about translating dates in different formats/languages. But the problem is when I include the **date** function into it, it seems not to work. Do you know why ? I made my code lighter with essentials in order to understand the problem :

```
class Test {

    public function test($timestamp, $format='d/m/Y') {
        return date($format, $timestamp);
    }

}
```

Ok, here is the full class...

```
class GetDateTime {

    private $_text_en_US = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June", "July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December");

    private $_text_fr_FR = array("Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche", "Janvier", "F&eacute;vrier", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Ao&ucirc;t", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "D&eacute;cembre");

    public function getDateTime($format='d/m/Y', $timestamp, $locale='fr_FR') {
        switch ($format) {
            case 'd/m/Y':
            case 'm/d/Y':
                return date($format, $timestamp);
            break;  
            case 'l d F Y':
                return str_replace($_text_en_US, ${'_text_'.$locale}, date($format, $timestamp));
            break;  
        }
    }

}
```

...and how I call it :

```
include_once (BASE_DIR.'/lib/dateTime.class.php');
$dateTime = new GetDateTime();
```

The fact is it's not translated when I call :

```
echo $dateTime->getDateTime('l d F Y', date());
```

Comment: Show us how you are calling this class.

Comment: `doesn't work` is **not** a precise error description.

Comment: Also any errors or otherwise describe "it seems not to work".

Comment: Modern versions of PHP already have classes for manipulating dates and times, why not just use one of those?

Comment: How do you instantiate the class? How is the function called? **Provide us some more essential details about your script...**

Comment: And the value of `$timestamp` is....?

Comment: Seems like "Elvis has left the building".

Comment: I'm sorry, I lost my Internet connection. I've updated the code.

Comment: You're re-inventing the [wheel](http://php.net/datetime) and not very well I have to say.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably confused why the method doesn't return what you wanted to.

`new Test(time())` doesn't return formated date, because method `test` is the same name as class, and because of that, `test` method becomes constructor of that class. You cannot return values from constructor, because when you create object, reference to that object is returned.

Rename your method `test` to something different, initialize class, and call that new method like:

```
$obj = new Test;
echo $obj->new_method(time() + 3600);
```