# I can't translate a date through a class

Tags: php, class, date, translate

I wrote a class in order to translate a date in different languages/format. I'm sorry, I repost this problem because last time I've posted it I lost my Internet connection and people left the thread...

Here is the full class...

```
class GetDateTime {

    private $_text_en_US = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June", "July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December");

    private $_text_fr_FR = array("Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi", "Dimanche", "Janvier", "F&eacute;vrier", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Ao&ucirc;t", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "D&eacute;cembre");

    public function getDateTime($format='d/m/Y', $timestamp, $locale='fr_FR') {
        switch ($format) {
            case 'd/m/Y':
            case 'm/d/Y':
                return date($format, $timestamp);
            break;  
            case 'l d F Y':
                return str_replace($_text_en_US, ${'_text_'.$locale}, date($format, $timestamp));
            break;  
        }
    }

}
```

...and how I call it :

```
include_once (BASE_DIR.'/lib/dateTime.class.php');
$dateTime = new GetDateTime();
```

The fact is it's not translated at all when I call :

```
echo $dateTime->getDateTime('l d F Y', time());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956423/date-function-into-a-class-doesnt-work

Comment: @perdeu : did you read what I've wrote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the second argument of the `getDateTime` method you're expecting a `timestamp` but you're passing the result of `date()` function which is *empty string*. Replace it with `time()` function.

```
echo $dateTime->getDateTime('l d F Y', time());
```

**EDIT**:
How could I have missed that! You're refering to local variables, not object's properties. Use `$this` keyword in your last `case` condition:

```
return str_replace($this->_text_en_US, $this->{'_text_'.$locale}, date($format, $timestamp));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made an error. I'm mean, of course it's time() and not date(). Still the same problem.

Comment: So tell me, what's the output? Is it empty or is it the unchanged string (with english months names)?

Comment: it's unchanged string. (not translated)

Comment: See my edit. I hope this time it will help.

Comment: GOT IT ! Shame on me... Thanks a lot matewka, you made my day ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What about [`strftime`](http://us1.php.net/strftime)? You can set your locale settings and get the translated date.

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
    echo strftime("Today is %A (in French) and the date is %B %d, %Y");

    // Outputs something like that: Today is mercredi (in French) and the date is novembre 13, 2013
?>
```